# Why an Image Object with a 32-bit PNG picture data inside returns a '24' when calling Image.getImageData().depth?

Tags: java, image, swt, png

I loaded a 32 bits' PNG data to a Image object in java/swt, but when i tried to get the parameter 'depth' of the imageData, it results a 24, is there anything wrong? Thanks.

```
image = new Image(display,"C:/JavaPic/foo.png"); //32 bits
image.getImageData().depth; // results 24
```

Comment: Did you check for an alpha channel? That could be your other 8 bits.

Comment: It seems that alpha dose work, thank you!